# How to prevent memory leak when calling promise in a loop

Tags: nativescript

I seem to get an error

> ActivityManager: Process nl.xxxx.yyyy(pid 21526) has
>   died: fore TOP (2411,292) ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on
>   unknown pid: 21526

when i call undermentioned function in a loop. In about 200 calls the error appears. It does not look like it is a timing problem, because even if i call the function in a timeout of 3 seconds (after the pomise has returned) it dies after about 200 cycles . I tried putting all variables outside the function , setting the variables to null but nothing seems to help. I have googled my fingers to the bone, but nothing came up... has anybody got a clue what i need to do ??

```
function testrun(f)
{
        // initially called with f = 0
        if(f > 500) return; // limit test to 500 cycles
        console.log ("fire :"+ f); // show the cycle you're in
        getMyThumb("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_20190710-092009_ScanApp.jpg")
        .then( thumb =>
        {
            console.log(thumb);
            setTimeout(() => 
            {
                testrun(f+1);
            }, 5000);   // tried setting timeout from 100ms to 5 seconds per cycle... All bugg out at ca. 200 cycles            
        })
        global.gc(); // testd with\ without  garbage collection     
}


global.getMyThumb = function name(filepath) 
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>
    {
       global.gc(); // tried with \ without   garbage collection here 
       imageSource = imageSourceModule.fromFile(filepath);
        try
        {
            var mutable = BitmapFactory.makeMutable(imageSource); 
            var ThumbBitmap = BitmapFactory.asBitmap(mutable).dispose((bmp) =>
            {   
                var optisizestring = "25,25";
                test =  bmp.resize(optisizestring); 
                base64JPEG = test.toBase64(BitmapFactory.OutputFormat.JPEG, 75);
                img = imageSource.fromBase64(base64JPEG);
                resolve( "data:image/png;base64," + base64JPEG);                
                global.gc(); // tried with \ without   garbage collection here
             });
        } catch(ex) { console.log("errds " + ex); resolve (null);}
    });
}
```

Comment: As you are processing bitmap you may need more memory, did you try setting `android:largeHeap="true"` on your application tag.

Comment: Try calling `recycle()` on your imageSources to release the bitmap from memory: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory. It seems Nativescript's ImageSource never calls it.

Comment: I had the  largeHeap set to  "true" but that makes no difference.

Comment: recycle() does not work. I have a higher version (3.0 apk), but recycle is not a recognised function ...

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap does not work in my situation either. My code does not reuse any bitmaps. i fetch files from the DCIM directories, and make thumbnails wichh i display. the function above returns the base64JPEG from the  image i got from the imageSource. (  imageSource = imageSourceModule.fromFile(filepath);)  so it may be removed from memory or reused but somehow it stays in memory...